# Wootheme 'Function' mobile select box nav breaks desktop dropdown nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile, woothemes

I'm using the Wootheme called Function, which has mobile styling and navigation built in. There is a select box for mobile screen widths that is added in place of the top navigation, but I'm having issues with it.

First, the select box is added to `div#top` at 781px screen width rather than the standard switch to mobile at widths less than 768px.

Second, and the main issue, is that the initiation of the select box adds inline styling of `overflow: hidden;` to the original `nav ul`, breaking the drop-down functionality of that menu once the screen width is increased again.

Ideally, I'd like the select box to not show up until less than 768px screen width and to remove the inline styling that breaks the original navigation drop-down. I've found references to the mobile menu in general.js and third-party.js files. Nothing looks incorrect, but the mobile menu plugin is minified, making it difficult to tell what's going on.

Edit: originally included link to problem site, but now it's fixed. It's seems like it was a problem with the plugin included below.

I'm not sure how helpful this is, but the minified javascript plugin is below:

```
(function(a){a.uniform={options:{selectClass:"selector",radioClass:"radio",checkboxClass:"checker",fileClass:"uploader",filenameClass:"filename",fileBtnClass:"action",fileDefaultText:"No file selected",fileBtnText:"Choose File",checkedClass:"checked",focusClass:"focus",disabledClass:"disabled",buttonClass:"button",activeClass:"active",hoverClass:"hover",useID:true,idPrefix:"uniform",resetSelector:false,autoHide:true},elements:[]};if(a.browser.msie&&a.browser.version<7){a.support.selectOpacity=false}else{a.support.selectOpacity=true}a.fn.uniform=function(k){k=a.extend(a.uniform.options,k);var d=this;if(k.resetSelector!=false){a(k.resetSelector).mouseup(function(){function l(){a.uniform.update(d)}setTimeout(l,10)})}function j(l){$el=a(l);$el.addClass($el.attr("type"));b(l)}function g(l){a(l).addClass("uniform");b(l)}function i(o){var m=a(o);var p=a("<div>"),l=a("<span>");p.addClass(k.buttonClass);if(k.useID&&m.attr("id")!=""){p.attr("id",k.idPrefix+"-"+m.attr("id"))}var n;if(m.is("a")||m.is("button")){n=m.text()}else{if(m.is(":submit")||m.is(":reset")||m.is("input[type=button]")){n=m.attr("value")}}n=n==""?m.is(":reset")?"Reset":"Submit":n;l.html(n);m.css("opacity",0);m.wrap(p);m.wrap(l);p=m.closest("div");l=m.closest("span");if(m.is(":disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}p.bind({"mouseenter.uniform":function(){p.addClass(k.hoverClass)},"mouseleave.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.hoverClass);p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"mousedown.uniform touchbegin.uniform":function(){p.addClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseup.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"click.uniform touchend.uniform":function(r){if(a(r.target).is("span")||a(r.target).is("div")){if(o[0].dispatchEvent){var q=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");q.initEvent("click",true,true);o[0].dispatchEvent(q)}else{o[0].click()}}}});o.bind({"focus.uniform":function(){p.addClass(k.focusClass)},"blur.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.focusClass)}});a.uniform.noSelect(p);b(o)}function e(o){var m=a(o);var p=a("<div />"),l=a("<span />");if(!m.css("display")=="none"&&k.autoHide){p.hide()}p.addClass(k.selectClass);if(k.useID&&o.attr("id")!=""){p.attr("id",k.idPrefix+"-"+o.attr("id"))}var n=o.find(":selected:first");if(n.length==0){n=o.find("option:first")}l.html(n.html());o.css("opacity",0);o.wrap(p);o.before(l);p=o.parent("div");l=o.siblings("span");o.bind({"change.uniform":function(){l.text(o.find(":selected").text());p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"focus.uniform":function(){p.addClass(k.focusClass)},"blur.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.focusClass);p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"mousedown.uniform touchbegin.uniform":function(){p.addClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseup.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"click.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseenter.uniform":function(){p.addClass(k.hoverClass)},"mouseleave.uniform":function(){p.removeClass(k.hoverClass);p.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"keyup.uniform":function(){l.text(o.find(":selected").html())}});if(a(o).attr("disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}a.uniform.noSelect(l);b(o)}function f(n){var m=a(n);var o=a("<div />"),l=a("<span />");if(!m.css("display")=="none"&&k.autoHide){o.hide()}o.addClass(k.checkboxClass);if(k.useID&&n.attr("id")!=""){o.attr("id",k.idPrefix+"-"+n.attr("id"))}a(n).wrap(o);a(n).wrap(l);l=n.parent();o=l.parent();a(n).css("opacity",0).bind({"focus.uniform":function(){o.addClass(k.focusClass)},"blur.uniform":function(){o.removeClass(k.focusClass)},"click.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){if(!a(n).attr("checked")){l.removeClass(k.checkedClass)}else{l.addClass(k.checkedClass)}},"mousedown.uniform touchbegin.uniform":function(){o.addClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseup.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){o.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseenter.uniform":function(){o.addClass(k.hoverClass)},"mouseleave.uniform":function(){o.removeClass(k.hoverClass);o.removeClass(k.activeClass)}});if(a(n).attr("checked")){l.addClass(k.checkedClass)}if(a(n).attr("disabled")){o.addClass(k.disabledClass)}b(n)}function c(n){var m=a(n);var o=a("<div />"),l=a("<span />");if(!m.css("display")=="none"&&k.autoHide){o.hide()}o.addClass(k.radioClass);if(k.useID&&n.attr("id")!=""){o.attr("id",k.idPrefix+"-"+n.attr("id"))}a(n).wrap(o);a(n).wrap(l);l=n.parent();o=l.parent();a(n).css("opacity",0).bind({"focus.uniform":function(){o.addClass(k.focusClass)},"blur.uniform":function(){o.removeClass(k.focusClass)},"click.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){if(!a(n).attr("checked")){l.removeClass(k.checkedClass)}else{var p=k.radioClass.split(" ")[0];a("."+p+" span."+k.checkedClass+":has([name='"+a(n).attr("name")+"'])").removeClass(k.checkedClass);l.addClass(k.checkedClass)}},"mousedown.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){if(!a(n).is(":disabled")){o.addClass(k.activeClass)}},"mouseup.uniform touchbegin.uniform":function(){o.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseenter.uniform touchend.uniform":function(){o.addClass(k.hoverClass)},"mouseleave.uniform":function(){o.removeClass(k.hoverClass);o.removeClass(k.activeClass)}});if(a(n).attr("checked")){l.addClass(k.checkedClass)}if(a(n).attr("disabled")){o.addClass(k.disabledClass)}b(n)}function h(q){var o=a(q);var r=a("<div />"),p=a("<span>"+k.fileDefaultText+"</span>"),m=a("<span>"+k.fileBtnText+"</span>");if(!o.css("display")=="none"&&k.autoHide){r.hide()}r.addClass(k.fileClass);p.addClass(k.filenameClass);m.addClass(k.fileBtnClass);if(k.useID&&o.attr("id")!=""){r.attr("id",k.idPrefix+"-"+o.attr("id"))}o.wrap(r);o.after(m);o.after(p);r=o.closest("div");p=o.siblings("."+k.filenameClass);m=o.siblings("."+k.fileBtnClass);if(!o.attr("size")){var l=r.width();o.attr("size",l/10)}var n=function(){var s=o.val();if(s===""){s=k.fileDefaultText}else{s=s.split(/[\/\\]+/);s=s[(s.length-1)]}p.text(s)};n();o.css("opacity",0).bind({"focus.uniform":function(){r.addClass(k.focusClass)},"blur.uniform":function(){r.removeClass(k.focusClass)},"mousedown.uniform":function(){if(!a(q).is(":disabled")){r.addClass(k.activeClass)}},"mouseup.uniform":function(){r.removeClass(k.activeClass)},"mouseenter.uniform":function(){r.addClass(k.hoverClass)},"mouseleave.uniform":function(){r.removeClass(k.hoverClass);r.removeClass(k.activeClass)}});if(a.browser.msie){o.bind("click.uniform.ie7",function(){setTimeout(n,0)})}else{o.bind("change.uniform",n)}if(o.attr("disabled")){r.addClass(k.disabledClass)}a.uniform.noSelect(p);a.uniform.noSelect(m);b(q)}a.uniform.restore=function(l){if(l==undefined){l=a(a.uniform.elements)}a(l).each(function(){if(a(this).is(":checkbox")){a(this).unwrap().unwrap()}else{if(a(this).is("select")){a(this).siblings("span").remove();a(this).unwrap()}else{if(a(this).is(":radio")){a(this).unwrap().unwrap()}else{if(a(this).is(":file")){a(this).siblings("span").remove();a(this).unwrap()}else{if(a(this).is("button, :submit, :reset, a, input[type='button']")){a(this).unwrap().unwrap()}}}}}a(this).unbind(".uniform");a(this).css("opacity","1");var m=a.inArray(a(l),a.uniform.elements);a.uniform.elements.splice(m,1)})};function b(l){l=a(l).get();if(l.length>1){a.each(l,function(m,n){a.uniform.elements.push(n)})}else{a.uniform.elements.push(l)}}a.uniform.noSelect=function(l){function m(){return false}a(l).each(function(){this.onselectstart=this.ondragstart=m;a(this).mousedown(m).css({MozUserSelect:"none"})})};a.uniform.update=function(l){if(l==undefined){l=a(a.uniform.elements)}l=a(l);l.each(function(){var n=a(this);if(n.is("select")){var m=n.siblings("span");var p=n.parent("div");p.removeClass(k.hoverClass+" "+k.focusClass+" "+k.activeClass);m.html(n.find(":selected").html());if(n.is(":disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}else{p.removeClass(k.disabledClass)}}else{if(n.is(":checkbox")){var m=n.closest("span");var p=n.closest("div");p.removeClass(k.hoverClass+" "+k.focusClass+" "+k.activeClass);m.removeClass(k.checkedClass);if(n.is(":checked")){m.addClass(k.checkedClass)}if(n.is(":disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}else{p.removeClass(k.disabledClass)}}else{if(n.is(":radio")){var m=n.closest("span");var p=n.closest("div");p.removeClass(k.hoverClass+" "+k.focusClass+" "+k.activeClass);m.removeClass(k.checkedClass);if(n.is(":checked")){m.addClass(k.checkedClass)}if(n.is(":disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}else{p.removeClass(k.disabledClass)}}else{if(n.is(":file")){var p=n.parent("div");var o=n.siblings(k.filenameClass);btnTag=n.siblings(k.fileBtnClass);p.removeClass(k.hoverClass+" "+k.focusClass+" "+k.activeClass);o.text(n.val());if(n.is(":disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}else{p.removeClass(k.disabledClass)}}else{if(n.is(":submit")||n.is(":reset")||n.is("button")||n.is("a")||l.is("input[type=button]")){var p=n.closest("div");p.removeClass(k.hoverClass+" "+k.focusClass+" "+k.activeClass);if(n.is(":disabled")){p.addClass(k.disabledClass)}else{p.removeClass(k.disabledClass)}}}}}}})};return this.each(function(){if(a.support.selectOpacity){var l=a(this);if(l.is("select")){if(l.attr("multiple")!=true){if(l.attr("size")==undefined||l.attr("size")<=1){e(l)}}}else{if(l.is(":checkbox")){f(l)}else{if(l.is(":radio")){c(l)}else{if(l.is(":file")){h(l)}else{if(l.is(":text, :password, input[type='email']")){j(l)}else{if(l.is("textarea")){g(l)}else{if(l.is("a")||l.is(":submit")||l.is(":reset")||l.is("button")||l.is("input[type=button]")){i(l)}}}}}}}}})}})(jQuery);
```

There is a demo of the theme - [Woothemes Function Demo](http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=function) - though it doesn't have a drop-down top menu.

Does anyone familiar with Woothemes have any ideas about where the inline styling is added to the original navigation and the screen width set for the mobile select menu?

Answer (score 0):

Had to replace the jQuery mobile menu plugin that was included with the theme and this fixed the issue with the drop-down on the original `nav ul`. The problematic plugin is located in the theme directory includes/js/third-party.js, at the top of the file.

To add the select menu at 767px instead of 781px, in includes/js/general.js in the call to the mobileMenu plugin around line 26, the switchWidth had to be changed to 750 to account for the way the javascript was getting the screen width. This part is a little buggy still, so I'm not sure exactly what the best fix is for it.